# Google chrome can't detect profiles

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, browser

I ran selenium python and the profiles in the browser disappeared:
[image]

However, the profiles are still located in the \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data folder:
[image]

why they were removed from the browser?
How can I make the browser detect them again?

UPD:
here's my code

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=C:\Users\Qwert\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
chrome_options.add_argument(r'profile-directory=Profile 3')

chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")  # this
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-web-security')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: those are basically preferences saved when adding profiles in a browser session.   When Chromedriver launches the browser, everything is fresh.  (basically a new and temporary config or ini file at launch... you can write/set prefs if they are needed... options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs-dict);

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any of your code so I'm unsure of how you're setting up selenium but by default Selenium starts Chrome with a fresh profile.

Pretty sure you've been doing this but if you want Selenium to use a specific profile you can point to it using `--user-data-dir`, like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:/path/to/your/profile')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

If you've done this and are still having this problem I'd make sure chrome isn't running before you launch your script as well as restoring your chrome profile. If all else fails, I'd reinstall Chrome.

Comment: I reinstalled the browser, but the error remains

Comment: @Denzel could you share your code for me please?

Comment: question updated with code

Comment: your code looks to be fine, i would comment out your chrome arguments and see if those are having any effect on it. i would also possibly switch to manually specifying the webdriver because chromedrivermanager can sometimes be incompatible.